# php echoing unwanted less-than sign

Tags: php, html

I have this code:

```
echo '<center><h3>More Information</h3><br>';
if ( $story == '') {
} else {
   echo '<h5>'.$story.'</h5>';
}
echo '<table id="tablepress-2" class="tablepress tablepress-id-2">
   <thead>
      <tr class="row-1 odd">
        <th class="column-1"><div>Service</div></th><th class="column-2"><div>Price</div></th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody class="row-hover">';
```

And the result is displaying multiple less-than signs '< < < < < < < <' right after 'More Information'. I dont know where are they coming from.

This is the result:

---

**More Information**

< < < < < < < <

Comment: not from that code. `<center>` tags? What is this, 1998?

Comment: you didn't close the <center> tag too

Comment: @sevenseacat Yes, I pointed out that too but this website belongs to someone and he said I cant change the center tag :3

Comment: So are they `<` or `&lt;`?

Comment: @adam that didn't fixed it

Comment: what does $story resolve to?

Comment: @zekms When I select View Page Source, I cant find it. They are nowhere in the php code. They are appearing here only

Comment: @KaiQing It is a normal text..

Comment: chuckles , to simplify `if(!empty($story)) { echo '<h5>'.$story.'</h5>';} `

Comment: What is $story? Which branch is it taking in the if there?

Comment: normal text may appear so, but we don't know where this normal text came from. If it is pasted from word or some other weird source it can have encoding issues that result in display anomalies. Have you tried var_dump($story) to see additional info on the string?

Comment: @DrixsonOseña No luck.. :/

Comment: @Albab what is the output of `$story`??

Comment: Well if we're guessing tag closings here, don't you need to close the table?

Comment: @Drixson $story is extracted from database and it contains normal phrase like '

Comment: @MillieSmith Its a long code, I have closed everything. It is a small extract of the code

Comment: Why don't you try this - Just delete everything after the if statement. If you still get the error, you know it's in that conditional. Next step, replace story with any static string. If you still get the error, call a witch doctor.

Comment: Can you pastebin the code? I bet the error is not in this snippet.

Comment: @KaiQing Earlier the if code was not there, it still displayed it. So it guess that's not the issue.

Comment: @MillieSmith Here you go http://pastebin.com/VGTEsSC4

Comment: Yep look at all the lines like line 37. you're echoing `<</tr>`

Comment: Looks like a bad case of copy paste.

Comment: @Albab Plus you've got a lot of `</td><` which make up for your multiple `<` - In your editor, search `</td><` and replace `</td>` will do the trick.

Comment: @MillieSmith Hah! So silly of me lol. It was at the end of the line so it didn't came to my notice. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @MillieSmith Yes, its a Tablepress code (wordpress plugin) I copied it from page source to use it in php/html.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thaknks a lot Fred! That fixed it :)

Comment: @Albab You're welcome. Let's close this question by accepting my answer. Glad to have found the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your pastebin file: http://pastebin.com/VGTEsSC4

You've got a lot of `</td><` which make up for your multiple `<` symbols.

In your editor, do a search `</td><` and replace `</td>`